# odoo return wizard from onchange method

Tags: python, onchange, product, odoo

From what i read you cannot return an action from an onchange function. But I want to show a dialog of some sort when a user changes the product within an orderline. The goal is to check if the product contains has_newproduct = True. In this case I want to ask the user if they want to delete the origin product (since it will not be needed).

I am overriding the onchange function of purchase order line like this:

```
class api_advanced(models.Model):

_inherit = "purchase.order.line"
has_newproduct = fields.Boolean("New Product")

@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    _logger.debug("------------------- OLD PRODUCT ID ----------------")
    _logger.debug(self._origin.product_id)
    _logger.debug(self._origin.has_newproduct)
    _logger.debug("------------------- NEW PRODUCT ID ----------------")
    _logger.debug(self.product_id)
    _logger.debug(self.has_newproduct)
    # Code to fire wizard is here but it does nothing...
```

How would i have to acomplish something similar? Or do i have to do something totally different? I could just delete the product without asking but that's not really the goal here...

Answer (score 0):

How you open wizard. when you click on button odoo calls a method, 
method return a dictionary to the client side. the client side will
examine the returned value. client side know that this is an action to open a view.

What i'm trying to say this behavior is defined in javascript so if you
want some thing like that you should extends the form view to handle 
the returned value from onchange event to open a wizard.

Or you can just add a button to the tree view with text ***delete orignal product***
that button will appear only if `has_newproduct = True` (use related field to add it to tree so you can use it in `attrs`). The user will know that he can delete the orignal
product if he see that button and you can add confirm message to explain what 
are the consequence of that operation.

Comment: I like the button idea, but i see 2 problems. If the user will see the button he cannot delete a product that is linked to a purchase order line. So he should only be able to do this once he changes to product. Second lets say you only show the button if the product is changed, how would you then know the previous product id?

Comment: Didn't understand your needs. But if you want to know the previous product you need to save it first. Add a field to purshase order when the user change the product save it in that field